# Event in Maya API after dependency graph was evaluated

Tags: python, maya

I am translating Maya nodes to external application interactively. I have registered callbacks for nodes with `MNodeMessage::addAttributeChangedCallback()`. It works fine and I can translate nodes directly in callback. However it does not recognize changes due to scripted expressions.

I've tested that `MNodeMessage::addNodeDirtyPlugCallback()` recognizes these changes properly. In callback I simply mark nodes that need update, as I need to wait till dependency graph has been evaluated, to get proper values.

I can run translation of marked dirty nodes on `MEventMessage::addEventCallback("idle")`, which works for GUI. However, it fails (translation is not triggered on time) when nodes are changed with script.

I've noticed that it works when forcing processing of idle messages with `maya.utils.processIdleEvents()`, but that defeats the purpose of callbacks.

Is there a reliable callback that is triggered once dependency graph has been evaluated?

Note, I've tested `MDGMessage::addForceUpdateCallback` and it does not work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You should try `MCommandMessage` or `MUserEventMessage` class.

```
import maya.OpenMaya as om

def anyFunc(someData):
    # something
    pass

# Registering an event
om.MUserEventMessage.registerUserEvent('anyEvent')

# Setting a size of event
om.MUserEventMessage.setUserEventSize('anyEvent', 4)

# Telling Maya to run a function
id = om.MUserEventMessage.addUserEventCallback('anyEvent', anyFunc)

# Making the event happen
om.MUserEventMessage.postUserEvent('anyEvent')

# Removing the callback function when done
om.MUserEventMessage.removeCallback(id)
```

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit, please?

Comment: I've checked `MCommandMessage1` before, but this line from documentation: `It is only called when actual commands are executed and not when scripts are executed.` suggested it's not suitable for my needs.
Concerning `MUserEventMessage` could you give an example, how should it be used in this case?

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but I don't see how it could be useful here. I know how to register such events. The problem is that I don't know when graph has been fully evaluated. I don't see how posting custom events could help with that.